# How to install OFBiz without ecommerce

Tags: ofbiz

If I don't need ecommerce, should I simply comment load-component component-location="ecommerce" in component-load.xml under specialpurpose?

I don't need some applications, if I comment them in component-load.xml under applications, there will be problems. How to know their dependencies?

sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can comment out the ecommerce component in the component-load.xml. This is not possible with every component in OFBiz, because there are dependencies between them (for example, you will always need the party component).

You will find an overview of the dependencies in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Component+and+Component+Set+Dependencies